# Problem with arabxetex transliteration

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, arabic

I have a problem with Arabic transliteration in arabxetex.

When I run the code below I get the transliteration as shown in the attached image.  The transliteration is just the italicized version of the input text.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{arabxetex}         

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.5]{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}

\begin{arab}[trans]
^gu.hA wa-.hamIruhu al-`a^saraTu
i^starY ^gu.hA `a^saraTa .hamIriN.
\end{arab}

\begin{arab}[voc]
^gu.hA wa-.hamIruhu al-`a^saraTu
i^starY ^gu.hA `a^saraTa .hamIriN.
\end{arab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What did you you expect for the transliteration? It _is_ the italic version of the input. You can change it to upshape with `\SetTranslitStyle{\upshape}`

Comment: My question is related to the transliteration actually.  If you see the output text, it is not transliterated. If everything runs well, then the text will be transliterated according to Library of Congress standard.

Answer (score 1):

you have to define a main font with `\setmainfont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{arabxetex}         
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.5]{Scheherazade}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
%\SetTranslitConvention{dmg}
\begin{document}
...
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot that solved the problem.  Its a pity this is not mentioned in Arabxetex manual.